# Get ID of currently opened document on Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how to get the ID of currently opened document on Google Apps. Even though I researched on Google, I couldn't find anything useful.

The function that I expect to use is `DocsList.getFileById()`, but it seems no way to get the opened document ID.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app?hl=en#getActiveDocument%28%29).

```
// Get the id of the document to which this script is bound.
var docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
```